# Infinite scrolling for personalized recommendations

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, indexing

I've been recently researching solutions that would allow me to display a personalized ranking of products in an online e-commerce store.

A natural solution for this problem would be to use a managed ML service such as
*AWS Personalize*.

Based on my understanding it can be implemented in terms of 2 service calls:

- *Recommendations* - return up to ~500 products based on user's profile
- *Ranking* - based on product ids (up to ~500) reorder the list according user's to profile

I was wondering if there exists and implementation / indexing strategy that would allow to display the entire product catalog (let's assume 10k products)?

I can imagine an implementation that would:

- Return 50 products per page
- Call recommendations to grab first 500 products
- Alternatively, pick top 500 products platform-wise and rerank them according to the user.
- For the remaining results, i.e. pages 11 to N a database query would be executed, excluding those 500 products by id. The recommended ordering wouldn't be as relevant anymore as te top recommendations have been listed and the user is less likely to encounter relevant results at the 11th page. As a downside such a query would need a relatively large array to be included as a part of the query.

Is there a better solution for this? I've seen many eccomerce platforms offering a "Recommended" order option for their product listing that allows infinite scrolling. Would that mean that such a store is typically using predefined ranks, that is an arbitrary rank assigned to each product by the content manager that is exactly the same for any user on the platform?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen an ecommerce site that shows me 10K products without any differentiation. Most ecommerce sites use a process called "[merchandising](https://sleeknote.com/blog/e-commerce-merchandising)" to decide which product to show, to which customer, in which position/treatment, at which time, and in which context.

Personalized recommendations may be part of that process, but they are generally only a part. For instance, if you're browsing "Books about architecture", the fact the recommendation engine thinks you're really interested in CDs by Duran Duran is not super useful. And even within "books about architecture", there may be other attributes that are more likely to drive your buying behaviour.

Most ecommerce sites use a range of attributes to decide product ranking in a product listing page, for example "relevance", "price", "is the product on special offer?", "is the product in stock?", "do we make a big margin on this product?", "is this a best seller?", "is the supplier reliable?". Personalized recommendations are sprinkled into these factors, but the weightings are very much specific to the vendor.

Most recommendation engines will provide a "relevance score" or similar indicator. In my experience, this has a long tail distribution - a handful of products will score highly, and the rest will score very low relevancy scores. The ecommerce business I have worked with have a cut off point - a score of less than x means we'll ignore the recommendation, in favour of other criteria.

Again, in my experience, personalized recommendations are useful for squeezing the last few percentage points of conversion, but nowhere near as valuable as robust search, intuitive categorization, and rich meta data.

I'd suggest that if your customer has scrolled through 500 recommended products, it's unlikely the next 9500 need to be in "recommended" order - your recommendation mechanism is probably statistically not significant.

Comment: I think embracing that limit it's a very common sense solution to this particular real-life problem. On the other side I'm still curious about the algorithmic concept of infinite recommendations - a social media feed could be another use case where such algorithm could be applied. I am looking at this from the perspective of a relatively small startup where a couple of devs need to provide an entry-level solution rather than trying to directly mirror what Instragram or Amazon would describe in their tech blogs.

Comment: Social media feeds are very different to ecommerce product catalogues - the UI might look similar, but they can use "time" as a major way of deciding what to show - newest latest for people you follow, with a sprinkling of "recommendation" on top.